# Split vector of class into vector of class member

Tags: c++, class, vector

I found a problem in C++ that I cannot solve by myself and so I would like to ask you,
if there is a possibility to split **vector of *class*** into **vector of *class member***.

```
class CPerson
{
 public:
    string m_Name;
    string m_Surname;
}
    
class CPersonList
{
 public:
    CPersonList ( const vector<CPerson> & ref )
    {
        m_List = ref;
    }
 private:
    vector<CPerson> m_List;
}

class CAllPersonsData
{
 public:
    CPersonList "MYPROBLEM" ( ) { CPersonList listAlfa ("IDONOTKNOW"); return listAlfa; }
 private:
    class CData
    {
     public:
        CPerson m_Person;
        string m_Data;
    }

    vector<CData> m_Alldata;
```

"MYPROBLEM" is a method which should create and return CPersonList listAlfa.

*listAlfa* should be created by constructor, where I would like to pass *vector* created from *vector*. In my eyes, "IDONOTKNOW" should look like *vector<CData.CPerson>*. So, there should be same data as in *vector* but without atributes *m_Data*.

Is there any option how to do this?

Of course I do not want to copy it, because I would like to pass it just by reference.

Thank you so much for your tips ;-)

Comment: Do you need a `std::vector` or can it be something vector-like that can be iterated over?

Comment: You can't have a vector of CPerson unless you copy the CPersons. Would a vector of pointers do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A vector owns its content so if you want to return a `std::vector<CPerson>` you would have to copy the data, for example

```
std::vector<CPerson> people;
people.reserve(m_Alldata.size());
std::transform(m_Alldata.begin(), m_Alldata.end(), std::back_inserter(people), 
               [](CData const & data) { return data.m_person; });
return people;
```

If you want to return a vector of "references" to the instances in `m_Alldata`, you could return a `std::vector<CPerson *>`:

```
std::vector<CPerson *> people;
people.reserve(m_Alldata.size());
std::transform(m_Alldata.begin(), m_Alldata.end(), std::back_inserter(people), 
               [](CData const & data) { return &data.m_person; });
return people;
```

or a `std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<CPerson>>`:

```
std::vector<std::refernce_wrapper<CPerson>> people;
people.reserve(m_Alldata.size());
std::transform(m_Alldata.begin(), m_Alldata.end(), std::back_inserter(people), 
               [](CData const & data) { return std::ref(data.m_person); });
return people;
```

As an alternative to a `std::vector` you could return a begin/end pair of iterators that dereference to a `CPerson`-reference:

```
#include <boost/compute/iterator/transform_iterator.hpp>

using boost::compute::make_transform_iterator;

auto people_begin()
{
  return make_transform_iterator(m_Alldata.begin(), [](CData const & data) { return data.m_person; });
}

auto people_end()
{
  return make_transform_iterator(m_Alldata.end(), [](CData const & data) { return data.m_person; });
}
```

If you can use the ranges-library you could return a transform_view of your data:

```
#include <ranges>

auto people()
{
  return std::ranges::transform_view(m_Alldata, [](CData & data) { return data.m_person; });
}
```

The returned object has a `begin()` and `end()` and its iterators dereference to a `CPerson &`.